# React Native Firebase gives error on device but works on emulator

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I'm new to React Native/Firebase. I followed [these](https://rnfirebase.io/) instructions to setup `@react-native-firebase/auth` for Android.
I have enabled Email/Password based login from my Firebase web console and have created a user for testing. I am calling Firebase auth using the following code snippet.

```
auth()
  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(userNameText, passwordText)
  .then(() => {
    navigation.navigate("ClientMainScreen");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    setSnackBarVisible(true);
  });
```

The thing is that this seems to be running without errors on my Android emulator on my Mac but when testing this out on a physical android device using `expo publish`, the app crashes when trying to execute this code snippet with the following error log in the Expo Client. What am I missing ?
[image]

For context, my `index.js` looks like this

```
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";

import App from "./App";

registerRootComponent(App);
```

and I'm using `react-native": "~0.62.2"`

Comment: are you using expo? ejected,  bare workflow or managed workflow?

Comment: Added index.js details. this might help explain the context. @StevenBell

Comment: is that managed expo?

Comment: I simply used create-react-native-app to create the project and have been using yarn android to run on my emulator. Does this help you in inferring your doubt ?